# Multi protocol VPN Client

Tags: networking, osx, vpn

We work for many companies and each one have a different VPN servers and protocols (Fortinet, Checkpoint, OpenVPN, ...).

I have installed dozen of VPN clients in my Mac. Is there any app that replace all of these clients in one app that handle all protocols properly?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ShimoVPN](https://www.shimovpn.com/)

> Shimo supports every major VPN protocol that is currently available:
>   The widely used CiscoVPN, the very secure OpenVPN and all
>   standard-compliant IPSec connections. It also handles Point-to-Point
>   Tunneling (PPTP VPN) and Layer 2 Tunneling (L2TP) protocols. Even
>   Cisco’s new Secure Socket Layer (SSL) protocol AnyConnect is supported
>   by Shimo – the most flexible VPN client for Mac. Shimo also enables
>   you to establish encrypted Secure Shell (SSH) connections including
>   port forwarding for secure web browsing.
>
> There is no other VPN client for Mac which supports this variety of
>   available protocols. If you want to have the all-in-one solution for
>   your secure connections, Shimo is technology of choice. This feature
>   is not only helpful, if you have to handle different types of
>   connections, but rather in cases where your system administrator
>   upgrades or changes the used protocol. With Shimo you are always
>   prepared and ready to go.